# Poor Webcam Video Quality in Zoom with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam, zoom-meeting

i have a Logitech C920 Webcam with great video quality in zoom with windows.

In Ubuntu the great quality is visible with **ffplay /dev/video0**

When i start Zoom (v5.16.1.8561) i see myself also in a great quality.

But the recording and what others see is really poor quality.

It seems, that the Zoom software send a poor quality to the web.

Anyone else with this problem and solutions?